# How to update multiple tables in kdb

Tags: kdb

Say I have a list of tables. (`sym1, sym2, sym3` etc)

How would I add a new column to each table called `Sym` containing the table name?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to achieve this :

```
q){update Sym:x from x}each `sym1`sym2`sym3
q)raze (sym1;sym2;sym3)
p        s  Sym
----------------
2.08725  75 sym1
2.065687 6  sym1
2.058972 63 sym2
2.095509 62 sym2
2.036151 90 sym3
2.090895 63 sym3
```

If you are getting these tables (`sym1,sym2,sym3`) as the output of another function call like :

```
f each `s1`s2`s3
```

then I'll suggest updating the function to add the column `Sym` just before return these individual tables.

```
f:{
   /some logic
   update Sym:x from t
  }
```

This will save an operation of adding a new column separately

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
q){@[value x;`Sym;:;x]}each tables[]
+`a`b`c`Sym!(0 1 2 3 4;0 1 2 3 4;0 1 2 3 4;`sym1`sym1`sym1`sym1`sym1)
+`a`b`c`Sym!(0 1 2 3 4;0 1 2 3 4;0 1 2 3 4;`sym2`sym2`sym2`sym2`sym2)
+`a`b`c`Sym!(0 1 2 3 4;0 1 2 3 4;0 1 2 3 4;`sym3`sym3`sym3`sym3`sym3)
```

If you remove `value` from the first argument of `@`, this will update the tables in place.

Otherwise, since this returns a list, you can use indexing to return the table you want from the list:

```
q)({@[value x;`Sym;:;x]}each tables[])0
a b c Sym
----------
0 0 0 sym1
1 1 1 sym1
2 2 2 sym1
3 3 3 sym1
4 4 4 sym1
```

Hope this helps,

James